# How to Extract Features from Text based on Fine-Tuned BERT Model

Tags: tensorflow, cpu-word, embedding

I am trying to make a binary predictor on some data which has one columns with text and some additional columns with numerical values. My first solution was to use word2vec on the text to extract 30 features and use them with the other values in a Random Forest. It produces good result. I am interested in improving the TEXT to FEATURE model.

I then wanted to improve the feature extraction algorithm by using BERT. I managed to implement a pre-trained BERT model for feature extraction with some improvement to the word2vec.

Now I want to know, how can i fine-tune the BERT model on my data - to improve the feature extraction model - to get better text-to-features for my Random Forest algorithm. I know how to fine-tune BERT for a binary predictor (BertForSequenceClassification), but not how to fine-tune it for a making a better BERT text-to-feature extraction model. Can I use the layers in the BertForSequenceClassification somehow?? I spent 2 days trying to find a solution, but did not manage so far...

Kind Regards, Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am dealing with this problem too. As far I know, you must fine-tune the BERT language model; according to [this issue](https://github.com/google-research/bert/issues/145), [masked LM](https://github.com/google-research/bert#pre-training-with-bert) is suggested. Then you can use [Bert-as-service](https://bert-as-service.readthedocs.io/en/latest/section/faq.html#can-i-use-my-own-fine-tuned-bert-model) to extract the features. Note that I haven't tested it yet, but I am going to. I thought it would be good to share it with you :)

Comment: Hey, thanks alot! I managed to get it to work after discussing it on Github. You can follow the discussion here https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/1323. I managed to get it to work with quite impressing results for my purpose. Let me know if you have any problems making a similar implementation.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your results! If I understood correctly, you used sequence classification task to fine-tune Bert. Then after 4 epochs, you extracted the last hidden layers as a sequence representation. Right? Then you used the extracted vector as your random forest's input. But one question. Why didn't you just finetune the model as I said? What was wrong with it? In my suggestion, the language model will be improved for your task.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that. But my purpose was to extract a feature vector and then afterwards use that vector together with several other columns values in a random Forrest model.

Comment: I think finetuning language model can fulfill your need too.

Comment: Only if the general model works best in a neural network. It just so happens that for my general problem - analysing a text field and several additional values - a random forrest algorithm gives better results than a neural network for my case. Therefore it works best (higher accuracy) with subtracting a feature vector of fixed length from the text field and use that as additional input.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can fine-tune BERT, and then extract the features. I have done it, but it really did not yield a good improvement. By fine-tuning and then extracting the text features, the text features are slightly adapted to your custom training data. It can still be done in 2 ways. Use fine-tuning and then extract the features, or you can continue pre-training from BERT's checkpoint (apply MLM over your custom data), and then followed by feature extraction.